# Suppressing lint message lnt-accidental-copy 'auto' doesn't deduce references

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019 16.11.4, the following code gives me this lint message for the for() statement:

`lnt-accidental-copy 'auto' doesn't deduce references. A possibly unintended copy is being made.`

(This is a made up example, simplified from real code. I'm not really just printing a list of odd numbers.)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class SomeClass
{
  public:
    int i;
};

void SomeMethod(vector<SomeClass> vectorOfStuff)
{
    auto partIt = partition(begin(vectorOfStuff), end(vectorOfStuff), [](auto& x) {
        return (x.i & 1) == 0;
    });
    for (auto it = partIt; it != end(vectorOfStuff); ++it)
    {
        cout << "doing something with " << it->i << endl;
    }
    vectorOfStuff.erase(partIt, end(vectorOfStuff));
}
```

The suggested fix is to change the `auto it = partIt` to `auto &it = partIt`. Normally that is good advice, but in this case, I want to keep partIt unchanged for the call to erase() so I want a copy, not a reference.

According to the [announcement for the linter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/intellisense-code-linter-for-cpp/):

> Configuration: currently the feature is either enabled or disabled.
> There isn’t a way in the current version to enable/disable or change
> the severity of individual checks.

And I haven't found anything more recent about suppression.

One fix that I have come up with is to change the `auto it = partIt` to `auto it = next(partIt, 0)`. Another is to spell it out as `vector<SomeClass>::iterator it = partIt`. But those both look a touch clunky, and I'll have to add a comment to to explain I'm working around a lint message.

Is there a cleaner way to say "yes, I really want a copy of the iterator"? Or have I missed how to suppress the message in this instance?

Comment: If you don't need to announce what you're erasing, you could simplify things significantly with the erase/remove idiom. And your lambda doesn't need to capture anything.

Comment: I don't know why the lint message is shown, as `firstOdd` is an iterator, not a reference. You could also try `decltype(firstOdd) it = firstOdd` but that would likely need the same comment as your other alternatives to explain it.

Comment: Final unrelated thing from me: `& 1` is a more efficient odd number check than a modulo operation.

Comment: I lied. `vectorOfStuff.end()` would be better. Vectors have their own iterator members, and you don't `#include <iterator>` anyway.

Comment: I didn't get the message in VS2019 16.11.2, 16.11.3 or VS2022 preview

Comment: @sweenish This was cut down from real code. I just made up the even/odd number thing as a quick example. In the real code, the for loop is doing some work. (And the lambda does capture something there.) That said, if there is a standard idiom to loop through firstOdd->end, do stuff and erase, that would be great.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do you get the message for this code (from the linter announcement linked above):
void accidental_copy(vector<string> strings)
{
for (auto string : strings) {}
}

Comment: @TimothyByrd Yeah, that one I got.

Comment: @sweenish We happen to follow the guidance from Herb Sutter "Always use nonmember begin(x) and end(x) (not x.begin() and x.end())" https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/

Comment: In light of the clarifications that you’re posting, it seems that your [mre] needs to focus on just the issue at hand. It’s also incredibly rare to see someone attempt a legitimate mre, so kudos on that. As for Sutter’s advice, I’m still not completely on board, but the least you could do then is `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: I suggest you use `vector<SomeClass>::iterator it = partIt`, another method is to use `auto &it = partIt` and back up `partIt` to ensure the normal use of the `erase` .